# Two vertical Listviews having the same row height

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to display in my layout two ListViews (parallel vertically) having the same number of items, but the problem is that their heights are not synchronized.
So I would like to make their heights equals...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent_lf"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/aya_1"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/index"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0sp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.85"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="0.2sp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
```

Have any idea PLEASE!!

Thanks for all

Mohamed

Comment: your divider heights are not equal so your listviews are not syncd equally.

Comment: Are the individual items you are adding in both the list view have same height?

Comment: I added the divider but I got the same result...

Comment: Indeed, the items of each ListView haven't the same height. I don't know if I can recycle the Listview to reset the height..

Comment: A very simple solution is to assign custom rows to both your ListViews. Make sure you assign the same fixed height row to both.

Comment: Each row have a different height. So I can't fix this height. I want that the first listview's height (@+id/index) match the second listview's height (@+id/content).

Comment: If they have differente height, and you want both list to have the same height for each row, once you scroll one of the lists, you'll lost that "height sync", what make me think that you want to sync the scroll too (Am I wrong?). If that's the case, that's a terrible idea (it won't work as  you expect), you should have only one list with all the data in a single row (If it's not the case, well, you'll have that problem with the scroll I said before)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you want the left side listview to just display aditional information to whatever item is in the right side listview? Something like:

|1||second lv item|

Because if this is the case you are looking at the problem in a completely wrong angle.

Comment: @jvrodrigues this exactly what I want. And then I can convert this list to stickylist header

Comment: I think what you need is a custom adapter with a view that displays the information you want, you dont need 2 listviews for that.

Comment: I can not make it ( "|1|"|second lv item| ) sticky, it will be under the main element..

Answer (score 0):

you can write code like this to make equal list view :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/parent_lf"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/index"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0sp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="0.2sp"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: what was the problem are you want to showing this listview horizontally ? just copy and paste the code it will work .

Comment: No.. I want just that the heights of each row from list1 and list2 matches.

Comment: ok so just set the equal height of both listview same like layout_height="250dp" on both listview